# Laravel didnt find PHP Library RdKafka

Tags: php, laravel-5, apache-kafka

I'm getting

```
 Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
    Class 'RdKafka\Producer' not found
```

But the library is loaded at php.ini, when i try with php artisan tinker, it works, but doesn't work in the web application

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    $topicConf = new RdKafka\TopicConf();
    $topicConf->set('auto.offset.reset', 'largest');

    $conf = new RdKafka\Conf();
    $conf->set('group.id', 'php-pubsub');
    $conf->set('metadata.broker.list', '127.0.0.1');
    $conf->set('enable.auto.commit', 'false');
    $conf->set('offset.store.method', 'broker');
    $conf->set('socket.blocking.max.ms', 50);
    $conf->setDefaultTopicConf($topicConf);
});
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Im at the same point as you!

Comment: I realized that i can create a laravel command to run that on the CLI level, and it works, so you can just create a laravel command to run it and schedule it to run every single time you want.

Answer (score -2):

user with \

$conf = new \RdKafka\Conf();

Comment: $conf = new \RdKafka\Conf();
  $conf->set('log_level', (string) LOG_DEBUG);
  $conf->set('debug', 'all');
  $rk = new \RdKafka\Consumer($conf);

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some information, and reformat your example as code. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting